# Accepted job offer but employer is not responsive. What should I do?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, internship, job-acceptance

Well it wasn't exactly a job offer; I got an internship offer on April 2nd in New York. There was a lot of stuff I had to put into consideration like the job, money, housing, etc. But ultimately I did want it, so I accepted the offer about 3 days later. I emailed the lady back accepting the position, telling her my available days, explaining I took a while to respond because I was planning the move to the city but that everything was set. She never got back to me. So on April 11th, I emailed her a follow up email and still no response... I was starting to feel I might've lost my chance because I didn't respond immediately. A few days later she responded apologizing for her delay but that everything was set for me to start June 3rd but that was all; she didn't give me further information on my schedule and what not. I then kindly replied and asked her what time I should go in that day and how my schedule would look. Once again she's unresponsive. It's May 28, 5 days until my starting date and I haven't heard back. I feel a little worried since I feel she should've answered my question by now. I don't know if I should be because maybe she's waiting for the very last minute to give the information. I'm not sure what to do.. Should I give her a call tomorrow?

I even had another internship offer after I accepted this one but I denied it. Although this one wasn't responsive, I had done my research on the company and still wanted to work there; But now I'm starting to feel like I should've taken the other one.

Update: I will be calling today, thank you all for your input. I guess I wasn't hesitant to reach out to her again and didn't want to come off as annoying. I am still a little worried as to why she didn't respond my email in the first place? Makes me believe they are not so interested in me.

Comment: It's around peak vacation time. Maybe the people handling your onboarding were on vacation and you got lost in translation since it's been over a month. Reaching out again would be reasonable. Are there any other details you can provide such as the size of the company so we can give you the best answer possible?

Comment: Yea that's understandable, thank you. It's a fairly small PR company so I figure most of them are very busy with their work, which could be another reason why she is not responsive.

Comment: Why wait until tomorrow to call?

Answer (score 10):

> Should I give her a call tomorrow?

Yes.

Whenever you need specific answers to your questions, ask them in person or at least use the telephone. You can always send an email confirming what you heard if for some reason you need a "paper trail".

As you have seen, emails can more easily be ignored. Emails can also be answered partially. While convenient, email is not always the most effective communication method.

Just call. Do it today.

Answer (score 7):

> Should I give her a call tomorrow?

Yep. To be honest with 20/20 hindsight you might have tried calling earlier but realistically I think your best bet is probably to try calling now. You've still got a week or so to try getting hold of them by phone but in the worst case you have had written confirmation that " everything was set for me to start June 3rd" so you can pretty much just turn up on that date. If you haven't had any contact or more information regarding timings then show up about 5-10 mins before the start of their usual business hours and take it from there.

Comment: Yes, I will most definitely call today. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely calling them is a good idea, but as a side note, this would be a red flag to me.  Presumably the person you are working with for the hiring process is part of HR, and you have a picture of how HR operates in this company: they are not prompt with replying to inquiries, they often forget to do things, they need constant prodding to get anything done, and so on.  How does that make you feel if, after starting work, you need assistance with an HR-related matter?  You can expect this behaviour to continue with this company; do you still want to work for them?

Comment: The HR person may work on other tasks also. So he/she may be bogged down with unrelated things - which can easily have more priority than interacting with potential interns.